# Javascript: how to play sound file in Safari

Tags: javascript, audio, safari

In my `JavaScript` script, playing sound files in Chrome, Mozilla, and IE is simplicity itself. Safari, however, won't play them. I have four relevant functions, which are in essence:

```
function setAudioFile(){
    song_to_play = new Audio("my-song.mp3");
}

function playAudio(){
    song_to_play.play();
}

function pauseAudio(){
    song_to_play.pause();
}

function cancelAudio(){
    table_to_play.pause();
    table_to_play.currentTime = 0; 
}
```

where `song_to_play` is a global variable.

What I'm looking for is code that will do exactly the same thing in Safari.  The `setAudioFile()` would be modified as follows:

```
function setAudioFile(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 

    if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) { 
        song_to_play = ????

    } else {
        song_to_play = new Audio("my-song.mp3"));
    }
}
```

The other three files would be modified accordingly.

Help with the code I'm looking for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you define your `table_to_play` variable?  also please create an example of your issue at JSFiddle or some similar service

Comment: @falinsky Please don't advise users to post relevant code to an external site as those links can become broken over time. There's no reason this couldn't be posted right here.

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on `navigator.userAgent` as this can be spoofed. Instead, you should just set up the HTML `<audio>` element and provide several `<source>` options that cover all the compatible formats. If the `controls` attribute is not on, there will not be anything displayed on the page and then you can use JavaScript to implement your own set of controls.